# How to reimplement event and pass and argument to it using PySide

Tags: python, pyside

I am desperately trying to get the answer for a seems to be a very simple question. So, I have my main code which is a UI that has `QTextEdit` and I want to limit characters amount to 140. The best way, in my opinion, would be reimplementing `keyPressEvent` and `KeyReleaseEvent` functions.

To do that I am creating a class with my custom Text Edit widget:

```
class CustomTextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
   def keyPressEvent(self, event, text):
       if len(text) > 140:
           return
       else:
           self.setText(text)
```

I don't need an event here. I only need to pass an argument that will hold the text that is already written in the text editor. However, when I try to create a `QEditText` and pass the current text by saying in my main UI:

```
self.text_edit = QtWidgets.CustomTextEdit()
self.text_edit.keyPressEvent(self.text_edit.toPlainText())
```

the program understands it as if I am passing an event which is a `QKeyEvent` and of course says that it doesn't have length.

What am I doing wrong? How to pass an event and an argument? Is it even possible?

I have been reading tones of answers to a similar question but still, don't get the answer. Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keyPressEvent` can take only two arguments: `self` and `event` (named as you wish). To access the text already written in the editor you can use `self.toPlainText()` before accepting event with `event.accept()`. So, for your case to limit characters amount to 140 I would propose this workaround:

```
class CustomTextEdit(QWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        current_text = self.toPlainText()
        super().keyPressEvent(event)  # event.accept() is not working for me for some reasons
        if len(self.toPlainText()) > 140:
            self.setText(current_text)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it and Script Editor says  TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: You are using Python2.x, right? Try this line `super(QTextEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event)`

Comment: This worked!    class CustomTextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        current_text = self.toPlainText()
        super(CustomTextEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event)

Comment: You're a life savior!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help you :)